# Adding a new activity on button click

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm making a simple application and want to open a new `Activity` when I click a button. I have looked at a few tutorials online to do so, but I keep getting errors in my code that I dont quite know how to get rid of.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static Button button_convert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        onClick_Convert();

        public void onClick_Convert() {
        onClick_Convert = (button_convert) findViewById(R.id.button_convert);
        onClick_Convert.setOnClickListener (
                new View.onClickListener() {
                    public void onClick (View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.jamesk93.bmi_app.SecondActivity");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }




        final Button button_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calc);
        final EditText field_weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_height);
        final EditText field_height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.field_height);
        final TextView view_result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_result);
        final TextView view_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.view_msg);



        button_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {

                double weight;
                double height;
                double bmi;
                String msg = "";

                weight = Double.parseDouble(field_weight.getText().toString());
                height = Double.parseDouble(field_height.getText().toString());

                if (field_height.getText().toString().equals("") || field_weight.getText().toString().equals("")) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Valid Values", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

                } else {

                    bmi = height * height;
                    bmi = weight / bmi;

                    view_result.setText(String.valueOf(bmi));

                    if (bmi < 18.5) {

                        msg = "Underweight";

                    } else if (bmi > 18.5 && bmi < 25) {
                        msg = "Normal";


                    } else if (bmi > 25) {

                        msg = "Overweight";
                    }

                    view_msg.setText(msg);

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Im pretty sure it is my use of brackets and indenting that is generating the errors. Ive tried to reposition them but it doesnt seem to be solving anything.

If I comment lines 21-33 out which is the code for the `onclick` intent, it runs fine. If you need to see any of my other files, just comment which ones and I'll upload them for you.

Comment: getting error on Button Click?

Comment: replace your `Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.jamesk93.bmi_app.SecondActivity");` with `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);`

Comment: You have did not mention it correctly. It should be like below:
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);

Comment: Sorry, I didnt clearly explain what errors Im getting. Lines 24-25 both give me "Cannot resolve symbol type- onClick_convert" and line 46 gives me an error on "setOnclicklistener" which I think is due to indenting or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
private Button button_convert;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button_convert= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_convert);
    onClick_Convert();
}

public void onClick_Convert() {

    button_convert.setOnClickListener (
            new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

**EDIT:**

There are a few mistakes:

First:

You are trying to initialize "onClick Convert" but it was not declared, actually the name of your button is "button convert". And then you try to cast it with "button convert". You should cast your button with "(Button)"

Second:

You are trying to initialize your button inside the click event, you should initialized it before the event, because then your button will be null.

Third:

The correct syntax to start an activity is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.class, NewActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Hope this help you, I recommend you to take a look to this link: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Thank you. That seemed to fix it

Comment: Noticed my "onClickListener" was spelt wrong as well. Its always the small things ...